# How to interpret $d\vec s$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> If a vector function $\vec F: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ is given, and $\vec F=\vec F(\vec x)$, where $\vec x$ denotes position and $\vec x=\vec x(t)$, we define the integral $$I=\int_{C}\vec F \cdot d\vec x=\int^{t_b}_{t_a}\vec F(\vec x(t)) \cdot {d\vec x \over dt} dt \tag{1}$$
>   If we parametrize $C$ using the arc length $s$ of the curve then we can write $$\int_{C}\vec F \cdot d\vec x = \int_{C} (F_1dx+F_2dy+F_3dz)=\int_{C}\vec F \cdot d\vec s \tag{2}$$

My question:

1. Why can replace $d\vec x$ by $d\vec s$ in equation $(2)$?
2. What is the meaning of $d\vec s$ given that $s$ is the arc length and hence a scalar?

Comment: We can't. I think it's an error for the reason you quote in 2. It could be fixed by agreeing on some convention like "ds times the unit velocity vector"

Comment: @Justpassingby No I think there is some explanation, but I do not know what is the convention. This notation appears on the notes http://www.archim.org.uk/lecturenotes/ia/VC_2000.pdf , page 44.

Comment: on that same page the author says that it is a synonym for dx, which I find quite acceptable.

Comment: Arclength parametrization is used to give unit speed for particles on the curve.